# Regular views don't work when we are on iPhone?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I use MVC 4 with this custom displaymodeprovider. Even if I set it as "false" it still on iPhone returns mobile version, though I want to return regular version of the website. Please help

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new
        DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => false)
        });
```

I set the break point inside this this code and it calls, though it still return mobile version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I've figured out the problem

MVC 4 already has his own redirection for "Mobile" prefix. so to use custom logic we need to remove that DisplayModeProvider for "Mobile" prefix, like this:

```
        var mobileModel = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DisplayModeId == "Mobile");
        if (mobileModel != null)
        {
            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Remove(mobileModel);
        }

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new
        DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => <USE ANY YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC>)
        });
```

This answer will be very useful for people who want that their website will be available in both versions for iPad or iPhone or Android and we can for example store in coockie user selection which version of the website we should display in his device.