# Globally disable MVC mobile site from rendering

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a mobile version for an MVC website.
For temporary purpose, I would like to disable the mobile site completely.
Is there a setting that can be done in either web.config or global.asax to do this?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who needs a solution, I could disable mobile views in this way:

```
var mobileModel = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DisplayModeId == "Mobile");
if (mobileModel != null)
{
    DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Remove(mobileModel);
}
```

I adapted the solution from: [Regular views don't work when we are on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360730/regular-views-dont-work-when-we-are-on-iphone)